# Django JSONField contains list of values

Tags: django

I have values in 'codes' JSONField structured like this:

```
[{"x": "723"}, {"x": "614"}]
```

I need to get Events objects where event.codes "x" key is IN a list of values, for example ['723', '332', ..]

EDIT

The model is:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Events(models.Model):
    codes = JSONField(null=False, blank=True, default={})
```

Comment: I have no Idea what Django is. But, the simplest solution is to iterate over objects to retrieve the data. Be More specific about details.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield

Comment: If you show your model structure, i can help you with an example query.

Comment: sorry. I edit the question including the model. Thank you

Comment: Events.objects.filter(pk__in=list_of_values) ?

Comment: id is the key inside the json, not the pk of events. I rename it for clarify

Comment: `Events.objects.filter(codes__x__contains=['723','332', ..])` does this work?

Comment: nope, I obtain empty queryset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Events.objects.filter(codes__0__x__in=['723','332'])`

**UPD:** From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield):

> If the key is an integer, it will be interpreted as an index lookup in an array

You store `list` object in `codes` json attribute, so you can lookup it by index (in your case it's zero index).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14101575)

Comment: @Or Duan, "I need to get Events objects where event.codes "x" key is IN a list of values, for example ['723', '332', ..]", it was exact solution to the question, but without clarification, when author asks to explain how this works, i give him link to docs, where it already explained. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @devxplorer Please use the [edit] link to describe how the code works.

Comment: @JF all the information that you need to understand how the code works there at the link I gave you, I just did not want to copy-paste it. And it's a good habit to first search for information in the documentation, and ask questions later.

Comment: @devxplorer Thanks! The reason I asked you to do this was because if (when) the link 404s, the information is still available in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to search inside a list stored in JSONField, you need to use the syntax filter(codes__contains=[{"key": value}]). Note the [] used here.

So for your question we get:

```
from django.db.models import Q

qs = Events.objects.filter(Q(codes__contains=['723']) | Q(codes__contains=['332']))
```

If you need to cover more cases, you can chain more Q() calls to this statement.